# How to find outbound IP of azure function app runtime?

Tags: runtime, azure-functions

I am trying to identify the IP from which my azure function app is trying to connect the other app.
I know the IP can belong to list of outbound IPs. I need to know the specific one and that too when my function app code is running.

While finding solution I got this code as answer

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString()
```

But sadly, it's showing IP of some diffrent machine which doesn't even show up in outbound IPs.

Is there any specific code which can help me find which IP the current instance of function app belongs to?

Comment: you want to get the IPs from within the code of your Functions?! If so, I think there is no way around of using the Azure Management SDK

Comment: I want to know the exact IP on which the azure function was running. which I can use to trace on my FTP firewall to examine the in and outs.

Comment: Any luck on this? I want to do the same.

Comment: If you have a consumption plan, that won't be possible. Switch to a premium plan and connect your function to a VNET then you have the whole subnet.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured this thing out. The outbound ip and the ip on which azure function is running are different. They say azure function is a server less application. Which truly means there is no specific machine on which the app may run. So everytime when the function app runs it picks up a random machine from the pool of available machines to it. However the outbound ip is the ip which it uses to communicate the external environment. And it won't be available at the time when the function app is running. It's independent of the machine on which the function is running but it belongs to set of outbound IP address from function app property.

Comment: I need to give list of all ips of my azure function so that client can whitelist them into there network and i can access there apps. I do not want to use ASE as its costly . is there any another way?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses):

> Each function app has a set of available outbound IP addresses. Any
>   outbound connection from a function, such as to a back-end database,
>   uses one of the available outbound IP addresses as the origin IP
>   address. You can't know beforehand which IP address a given connection
>   will use. For this reason, your back-end service must open its
>   firewall to all of the function app's outbound IP addresses.

As I said in the comment: If you want to know those IP from within the Functions code (although I don't know why you would need that), you would need to use the Azure Management SDK to do something similar than what the powershell command in the link above does.

Comment: I need to give list of all ips of my azure function so that client can whitelist them into there network and i can access there apps. I do not want to use ASE as its costly . is there any another way?

Comment: One reason I would like to do this is, for instance, to know when the set of previously-available IP addresses has changed. Azure sends out a ton of bulletins and most of them don't apply to me, so when I miss them I'd like to throw an exception and get an alert from our functions.